# how to convert date text format like 2012.12.02 into 20121202?

Tags: excel

how to convert text date into plain numbers? like by given example

Please help to convert 2012.12.02 into 20121202. 2012.12.02 is text format of a date which i need in plain numbers like 20121202.

I will be highly thankful.

Comment: and what have you tried so far? what problems did you find? **Hint:** if you absolutely don't know where to start, see `DATEVALUE()`

Comment: You should be able to use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace periods with empty strings.

Comment: Doug Glancy soooooooo nice of you.... substitute function worked,,,,,,,

Comment: Doug Glancy, again i request your help. i need to convert time format 02:20:00 into 022000 . substitute function is not working on this but worked on date format. plz give an idea, how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For dates, @Doug has answered:

> use the SUBSTITUTE function to replace periods with empty strings

For times I suggest (assuming these are in a column, say A starting in Row1): select the column, apply Text to Columns (DATA > Data Tools) with Tab as the delimiter and at Step 3 choose Text. Then:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","")
```

in Row1 copied down to suit.